# CSS confusion about background-image in body element

Tags: html, css, w3c

I was confused by the background-image :

1. background-image in `div` element

   When the background-image is in a `div`, the image is placed within `div`.
2. background-image in `body` element

   When the background-image is in a restrained body, the image is placed outside the body element.

Can anyone tell me why?

**that's result**
[image]

**My code:**

```css
  body{
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 20%;
            left: 20%;
            border: 2px solid black;
            background-image: url('./alert.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
div{
             border:2px solid red;
             width:100px;
             height:100px;
             border: 2px solid red;
             background-image: url('./alert.png');
             background-repeat: no-repeat;
             position: absolute;
             top: 10%;
             left: 10%
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
</head>
  
<body>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Post your code and not a screenshot of it

Comment: code will be messed in this page....

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean? My comment was related to your screenshot of your code. That is a bad practice for question and answer in Stackoverflow since people how want to help have to re-write your code. Post a [mcve] so that is easier to help you

Comment: why would the code be a mess?

Comment: background-image property behaves differently when applied to body element vs a div element. Pretty straightforward question I think.. and it's obvious English isn't the poster's first language. People need to get off their high horse on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell why exact this is the case, I would guess that the `<body>` Tag has a special behavior, since it is supposed to be the root element of the whole page and normaly wraps everything. But the background Image or Color of a `<body>` Element always is located at the top left corner, the only way to position it otherwise is with the `background-position` CSS Property, which will actually **not** work with colors. To create a gap for the background color, you only can give the `<html>` Tag a background color, but I would think that this is more a workaround than an actual solution. Personally, I would always set the `margin` and `padding` of `<body>` to 0 and achieve further gaps with a `<div>` Wrapper element inside of `<body>`. Below are two working code examples to show how to set `background-position` and how to have a (fake) "margin" for a background color with the help of the `<html>` Tag. Oh yeah, and is there any reason, why your body is positioned absolute? Just wondering if there is any use-case for this.

Positioned Background for body

```css
body {
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150');
  background-position: 20px 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

"Margin" with the help of `<html>`

```css
html {
  background-color: #fff;
}

body {
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#q14.0) (my emphasis):

> The background of the root element becomes the background of the
>   canvas and covers the entire canvas, anchored (for
>   'background-position') at the same point as it would be if it was
>   painted only for the root element itself. The root element does not
>   paint this background again.
>
> For HTML documents, however, we recommend that authors specify the
>   background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element. **For
>   documents whose root element is an HTML** "HTML" element or an XHTML
>   "html" element that has computed values of 'transparent' for
>   'background-color' and 'none' for 'background-image', **user agents must
>   instead use the computed value of the background properties from that
>   element's first HTML "BODY" element** or XHTML "body" element child when
>   painting backgrounds for the canvas, and must not paint a background
>   for that child element. **Such backgrounds must also be anchored at the
>   same point as they would be if they were painted only for the root
>   element**.